# Cross-site json rpc : Python server side and Mozilla extension using Javascript client side

Tags: javascript, python, json, rpc, mozilla

I am building a Mozilla extension that contacts a Python application on a remote server to send and receive data. The Python application can be called using xml-rpc from a Python console. I am attempting to design a JSON-RPC that would contact the same application. Developing the Python server side, which can be accessed using python console, has been easy.  However, I am having difficulties making the Mozilla extension to connect to the Python server side.

**How do I make cross site JSON rpc calls?**  I have googled and read about many libraries,  but none of them seem to work. I am not sure if it is because of some origin policy or because my server side is not able to process the data.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://mimic-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/ js library, or just XMLHttpRequest. I'm just with the same problem, and i'm an absolute newby with js :(

mimic seems grat, even if i'm having problems parsing the data returned..